# Using variable for error code in MySQL with SQLSTATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to manage my own errors in MySQL using a procedure and an error message table named "error_messages".

How can I manage to select a specific error message in that table?

I would like to do something like this.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE throw_error_test (divisor INT)
BEGIN
  SET @errorCode = '45123';
  IF divisor = 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE @errorCode
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = SELECT message 
                       FROM error_messages
                       WHERE id = @errorCode;
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`SIGNAL` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html):

> The ***`condition_value`*** in a [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) statement indicates the error value to be returned. It can be an `SQLSTATE` value (a 5-character string literal) or a ***`condition_name`*** that refers to a named condition previously defined with [`DECLARE ... CONDITION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare-condition.html) (see [Section 13.6.7.1, “`DECLARE ... CONDITION` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare-condition.html)).
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> Valid ***`simple_value_specification`*** designators can be specified using stored procedure or function parameters, stored program local variables declared with [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare.html), user-defined variables, system variables, or literals.

Therefore, for the `MESSAGE_TEXT` you could use a user variable—but my preference would be for stored program local variables; however can't specify the `SQLSTATE` with a variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE throw_error_test (divisor INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE _messageText VARCHAR(128);

  IF divisor = 0 THEN
    SELECT message
    INTO   _messageText
    FROM   error_messages
    WHERE  id = '45123';

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45123' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = _messageText
  END IF;

END
```

For the avoidance of doubt, the underscore `_` prefixes are purely a convention that I adopt to avoid ambiguity—they are not a necessary part of a local variable name.

Comment: I'm still getting an error in Workbench at "_errorCode" in the SIGNAL SQLSTATE line.

The error is "Syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting TEXT_STRING"

Comment: @NickB: Aha, sorry - wasn't looking into that... the `SQLSTATE` must be a string literal.

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable instead of hardcoding the SQLSTATE? I'm trying to create a generic error thrower procedure.

Comment: @NickB: Per the manual citation quoted above, the only options are to use a literal or a declared `CONDITION` name.  You can't use a variable.

Comment: So we developed a workaround. We have created a procedure name "throw_error" which accept an error code as a parameter. MySql will always throw the '45001' error, but we will fetch the real error code and message from the 'error_messages'table. Thanks

Comment: Check my comment [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html#c12827)